# Problema para destruir DM do Delphi

Tags: delphi

No sistema usamos os DM do Delphi para fazer comando em SQL, porém eles são chamados de tela em tela, e as vezes uma tela usa da outra (ou mais). Só que isso causa estouro de memória, para resolver, estou matando os DM após fechar a tela, mas tem algum método pronto para verificar de tempos em tempos os abertos sem uso e fechá-los?

Answer (score 1):

É tranquilo fazer isto:

```
if (DM <> nil) then // Se é diferente de nulo
begin
  DM := nil;
end;
```

Ou ali onde mencionei `DM := nil;` você pode passar `FreeAndNil(DM);`

Exemplos para evitar Access Violation:

```
 Abriu Cadastro de Clientes --> DM Aberto.
 -- Abriu Tela que procura Estados --> Essa tela usa DM.
 -- Fechou a Tela que procura Estados --> Não pode fechar o DM
Fechou o Cadastro de Clientes --> Pode fechar o DM
```

Dessa forma você vai fazendo o controle das telas que usa o DM Principal, porem, o correto é o DM principal sempre ficar aberto enquanto a aplicação roda, cria-se DMs secundários como `DMClientes`, `DMetcetc`... Dessa forma ao fechar a tela de Clientes você fecha o `DMClientes` e sua aplicação não estará dependendo de mais nada desse DM!

Comment: Certo,mas se outra tela estiver usando ele, ele não vai destruir os valores ali dando access violation??

Comment: Abertos sem uso não tem como amigo, e sim, vai da Access violation! O Certo é pega o método que passei para você e sempre que fechar uma Tela que usa o DM se não for usar mais passa o método fechando! No meu sistema, tenho 1 DM principal que sempre fica aberto e tenho pequenos DMs para cada tela que tem q abrir e fechar frequentemente!

Comment: O problema e que se destruo uma que pode estar sendo usada por outra tela da access violation, pois o DM foi "destruido". Essa e minha duvida, alem de ter que fazer uma verificação em todo o código para verificar isso, existe algo "feito", para verificar se aquele MD esta sendo usado por uma janela pai(mesmo sendo 3 janelas antes por exemplo)?

Comment: Que eu saiba não tem amigo, a única forma é você mesmo controlar isto! Vou editar a resposta mostrando exemplos de como controlar!

Answer (score 0):

Com base no que você descreve e sem o código para saber o que você está fazendo, é um pouco difícil te ajudar. Mas vamos lá.

Uma abordagem seria você colocar, nesses DM's, o básico do básico. Ou seja: apenas os DataSets que você vai de fato utilizar. Tudo que for acessório, você pode criar em tempo de execução. Neste caso, a herança poderá te ajudar muito, deixando a parte repetitiva do código no DMpai.

Outra coisa que pode ajudar é utilizar criar um singleton de conexão ou ainda criar um pool. Dependendo do banco que estiver utilizando, pode ser que as muitas transações/conexões estejam prendendo muito recurso sem liberar. Com a singleton/pool de conexões, você pode diminuir essa possibilidade de erro.

Outra questão é: Arrume a casa antes de sair do `DM`. Feche `DataSet's`, encerre as transações ativas, feche as conexões (ou as devolva para o pool). Outro detalhe é que se você está usando o `TFDQuery`, e o criando em tempo de execução, garanta  que irá destruí-lo (`Try... finally`) utilizando o Release ao invés do `Free` direto. O método `Release` faz liberações de memória que o `.Free` não faz. Não me pergunte porquê os dois estão públicos, porque eu não sei.

Por fim, caso o seu projeto tenha permita que você trabalhe com a mesma instância do `DataModule`, você só precisa construir uma fábrica  e uma classe singleton pra te devolver os DM de que você precisa.